# itertools.product with restrictions

Tags: python, python-itertools

Given the following lists of variables:

```py
greek = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
latin = ['x', 'y']
```

My baseline choice is `['alpha', 1, 'x']`. I'd like to generate the following variations, changing one parameter at a time:

```
variations = [
        ['beta', 1, 'x'], ['gamma', 1, 'x'],  # Varying greek
        ['alpha', 2, 'x'], ['alpha', 3, 'x'], # Varying numbers
        ['alpha', 1, 'y'],                    # Varying latin
        ]
```

I can generate the full matrix of all combinations with `it.product()`, and I can get the desired result in a few lines of code as well.

What is a nice, pythonic way to achieve that? Would be great to generalize that to many sets of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you iterate only over one place for each place in arrays:

```
greek = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
latin = ['x', 'y']

arrays = [greek, numbers, latin]

default = [arr[0] for arr in arrays]

for x, iter_arr in enumerate(arrays):
    #arr = [arr[0] for arr in arrays]
    iter_arr = arrays[x]
    for item in iter_arr[1:]:
        default[x] = item
        print(default)
    default[x] = arrays[x][0]
```

Can i ask for what purpose its done or does this iteration got a name?

Comment: Thanks for providing that! I don't know of a specific name; I'm using it to test variations from a baseline analysis, varying one parameter at a time. There is a large (10-20) number of parameters, each of which I want to test for a different range of values. Doing all possible combinations isn't possible, hence I only look at the effect of on parameter at a time.

Comment: if its so you may look at mashine learning algorithms, with input you want, to reduce data. What are you doing is sort of homework approach and does not cover all combinations of paratemers, but you should do that.

Answer (score 2):

A possible non-`itertools` solution is to use a generator with recursion:

```
def product(args, c = []):
   if not args:
      yield c
   else:
      for i in args[0]:
         yield from product(args[1:], c+[i])
```

---

```
greek = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
latin = ['x', 'y']
r, seen = list(product([greek, numbers, latin])), []
for i in r:
  if all(len(set(i) & set(k)) == 1 or i[0] != k[0] for k in seen):
    seen.append(i)

print(seen)
```

Output:

```
[['alpha', 1, 'x'], ['alpha', 2, 'y'], ['beta', 1, 'x'], ['beta', 2, 'y'], ['gamma', 1, 'x'], ['gamma', 2, 'y']]
```

Comment: I slightly updated the question (removed 'z'). The answer is great!

Comment: @DanielLenz Please see my recent edit. I updated the input to reflex your change.

Comment: This is close, but not quite what I'm trying to get. Only one parameter should vary at a time, here e.g. ['alpha', 2, 'y'] varies the number and the latin character at the same time.

Comment: @DanielLenz Do you mean that something such as `['alpha', 'y', 2]` should exist in the result as well? `['alpha', 2, 'y']` does exist in the output above. Can you clarify your desired restrictions? Thank you.

Comment: `['alpha', 'y', 2]` should *not* exist in the output above. Only one parameter should vary from the baseline parameters `['alpha', 'x', 1]` at a time.

Comment: @DanielLenz Please see my recent edit. I am still slightly confused, though, as in your `variations`, `['alpha', 2, 'x'], ['alpha', 3, 'x']` both vary from `['alpha', 'x', 1]` by `2` (`{'alpha', 'x'}` being in common).